# C++ Giving a global variable an initial value

Tags: c++, variables, global

I'm writing code in Visual C++ and I need to use a global variable. I know it's generally not a good idea, but in this case, it is necessary. I have created the variable and it is accessible from the function that needs it, but I can't figure out how to give it an initial value.

in the .h file it looks like

```
extern int lversion;
```

and in the .cpp file it looks like

```
int lversion;
```

How can I give this variable an initial value of 0?

Comment: I somehow have the feeling that all global variables that are floating around have had the exact same justification going on...

Comment: @PlasmaHH Unless someone is just too lazy to pass variables to a function. But that's some brand of lazy I've never even heard of. I discovered what I actually needed was to declare a static variable instead, so it turns out that I don't actually need one haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable does have initial value `0` as it is. Globals and statics are **value-initialized** unless otherwise specified. (for an `int`, it will be `0`)

If you want any other value, you can specify it:

In the **cpp** file:

```
int lversion= 3;
```

or

```
int lversion(3);
```

but for a value of `0` there's no point being this verbose.

Comment: Wasn't me. You were very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Adding these two lines in your .h and .cpp files respectively will allow you to initialize a global variable.

.h:

```
extern int Val;
```

.cpp:

```
int Val = 0;
```

Comment: It's more general way actually. You can set any value here, and also I prefere to initialize values explicit

Comment: I tried that. It gave me two errors. It's already been resolved however, so I don't think I'm going to go back and figure out what they were unless you really want me to.

Comment: That code does not give errors. I've just ckecked to be 101% sure )

Comment: @SSEMember this should work... Nothing wrong with this code, you probably forgot to include the header or something... or copy-pasted this code without renaming `Val` to what you have... Regardless, too verbose for my taste :)

Comment: It did for me for some reason. Probably because of some weird environmental settings I have coupled with using Visual C++. It's not my preference, but it's not worth arguing with my employer about either. Thanks for the help anyway. From both of you.